# Macbook Pro promo screenshots

Tags: macbook, screenshot

Are there any tools available that allow you to take promotional screenshots on  Macbook Pro? I see images such as the one below, and I wonder if there is a tool that puts a screenshot into a Macbook Pro frame and applies gloss affect for you, or does does this need to be done via a tool like Photoshop?

Example:
http://photos.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/macbook-pro-17in.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW (and not to cause a war) you could do the same thing with Skitch and Pixelmator.  Skitch is free, and Pixelmator is MUCH cheaper than Photoshop.  Anyway, I'm not saying this answer is better, just another set of tools that will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

That is basically done using the command + shift + 3 key combination, also known as screenshot. As for the gloss overlay, that is done in photoshop and isn't that hard at all. It is basically an object that is cut in that shape and has low opacity and a white fill. Post back if you want to learn how.

Either way, generally it would be a bad idea to use some kind of specific tool for that kind of thing simply because Photoshop is so powerful.

Comment: Hmm, there are tools for it for iOS, such as Simulator Cropper, that applies the iPhone frame and gloss effect. Figured there might be something similar for mac, mainly because all the screenshots I see have the exact same gloss effect applied in exactly the same way!

Comment: well the question was framed in such a way that it suggested you wanted to know the way in which they would make this image for a promo, and i guess i thought you were asking how the professionals would do it.